# Set widget background color

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qcheckbox

I use `QCheckBox` in `QTableWidgetCell`

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
layout->addWidget(checkBox);
layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
widget->setLayout(layout);
table->setCellWidget(0, 0, widget);
```

How can I change cell background?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code:

```
widget->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
```

works fine but you need to set the style for every container widget you add to your table:

So in order to see the change you need the following code:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
widget->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
layout->addWidget(checkBox);
layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
widget->setLayout(layout);

QWidget *widget2 = new QWidget();
widget2->setStyleSheet("background-color: red");
QCheckBox *checkBox2 = new QCheckBox();
QHBoxLayout *layout2 = new QHBoxLayout(widget2);
layout2->addWidget(checkBox2);
layout2->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
layout2->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
widget2->setLayout(layout);

ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0, 0, widget);
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0, 1, widget2);
```

And the result will be:

[image]

Comment: It works. But only last background changed cell has set background. Previous cells backgrounds recovered.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
checkBox->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");
```

If you want to specify it more generally, write the classtype in the CSS to indicate which class in the hierarchy should handle the flag. This could look something like this then:

```css
QWidget { background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change cell background, not a widget, use `setBackground()` method:

```
QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox("example");
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
layout->addWidget(checkBox);
layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
widget->setLayout(layout);
ui->tableWidget_2->setCellWidget(0,0,widget);
ui->tableWidget_2->item(0, 0)->setBackground(Qt::red);//this line should be
```

In this case all your cell will be red (without white lines around checkbox).

Comment: ui->tableWidget_2->item(0, 0)->setBackground(Qt::red); is dangerous because .setCellWidget doesn't create an item on that cell which return null pointer

Comment: The last line causes a crash because `item(0,0)` returns a null pointer.