# Qt: QTreeWidget - set selected item background color

Tags: qt, background-color, selecteditem

I'm making simple TODO-list in Qt, i want to "check" done items by changing their background color to green.
I was looking for many hours but i only found how to change the hilight color.
Can someone help me?

@EDIT

OMG, I'm sorry I forgot to write, I'm using QTreeWidget, I was trying to set the pointer to QTreeWidgetItem with

```
QTreeWidgetItem* ch = new QTreeWidgetItem();
ch = ui->TaskList->selectedItems();
ch->setBackground(0, Qt::green);
```

but it's not working.

I know how to set background on NEW item,

```
QTreeWidgetItem* tItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
tItem->setText(0,ui->lineEdit->text());
tItem->setBackground(0, Qt::red);
```

@EDIT2

OK, I get how to do it

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> ch;
ch = ui->TaskList->selectedItems();
foreach(QTreeWidgetItem * ch_item, ch)
ch_item->setBackground(0, Qt::green);
```

Comment: Without knowing what kind of objects you're using for your "items", it's not possible to answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set widget background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286138/set-widget-background-color)

Comment: put in some code example

Comment: Are you just selecting them to set them done or do you use the checkbox ? If so you can set the background in a stylesheet based on that property and you don't need to apply the background manually anymore.